# Importing images to prep for keras

Tags: image, python-3.x, csv, keras

I am trying to import a bunch of images and get them ready for keras. The goal here is to have an array of the following dimensions. (length, 160,329,3). As you can see my reshape function is commented out. The "print(images.shape) line returns (8037,). Not sure how to proceed to get the right array dimensions. For reference the 1st column in the csv file is a list of paths to the image in question. I have a function below that combines the path of the image inside the folder and the path to the folder.

When I run the commented out reshape function I get the following error.  "ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 8037 into shape (8037,160,320,3)"

```
import csv
import cv2

f = open('/Users/username/Desktop/data/driving_log.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)

m=[]
for row in csv_f:
  n=(row)
  m.append(n)

images=[]
for i in range(len(m)):
    img=(m[i][1])
    img=img.lstrip()
    path='/Users/username/Desktop/data/'
    img=path+img
    image=cv2.imread(img)
    images.append(image)
item_num = len(images)
images=np.array(images)
#images=np.array(images).reshape(item_num, 160, 320, 3)
print(images.shape) #returns (8037,)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you print the shape of an `image` before it is appended to `images` to verify it is what you expect? Even better would be adding an `imshow` in the loop to make sure you're loading the images you expect (only need to do for one or two). `cv2.imread` does not throw an error if there isn't an image at the file path you give it, so your array might be all `None` which would yield the exact behavior you've described.

If that is the problem, check the `img` variable and make sure it's pointing exactly where you want it to.

Comment: So the shape of image is (160,320,3) and print(images.shape) returns an error "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'"

Comment: @Jake3991 inside the loop are you able to display one of the images using `plt.imshow`?

Comment: plt.imshow(image) inside the loop gives the following error TypeError: Image data can not convert to float

Comment: plt.imshow(images[1]) outside of the loop brings up and image

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was including the first line of the CSV file which was heading.  After I sorted that out it ran great.  It gave me the requested shape.

```
images=[]
for i in range(1,len(labels)):
    img=(m[i][1])
    img=img.lstrip()
    path='/Users/user/Desktop/data/'
    img=path+img

    image=cv2.imread(img)
    images.append(image)
```